# jquery datepicker scrolls to top of page after date selected

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I know this question have been up for a few years ago, but I could not find relevant answer to my problem.

I have made a booking widget plug in seen on the middle on this WP page:
http://mattarahkka.com/the-lodge/#

Afte a date is selected the page scrolls to the top. The date picker remains open and the date remains selected. But why does the page jump to the top?

widget php code:

```
// include custom jQuery
functieon csf_booking_widget_custom_jquery() {

    /*   REGISTER JS FOR PLUGIN */
     wp_register_script('datepicker',plugins_url().'/csf-booking-widget/js/datepicker_2.js');
    /*   REGISTER CSS FOR PLUGIN */
    wp_register_style('jquery-ui','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
    wp_register_style('csf-happy-booking-widget',plugins_url().'/csf-booking-widget/css/happy-booking-widget.css');
    /*   CALL ALL JS FOR PLUGIN */
    wp_enqueue_script('jXquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
    wp_enqueue_script('datepicker');
     /*   CALL ALL CSS FOR PLUGIN */
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui');
    wp_enqueue_style('csf-happy-booking-widget');
}

function insert_booking_widget() 
    {
     $content = "<div class=\"bookingWidget\">";
     $content .= "<h2>Book Now</h2>";
     $content .= "<form method=\"get\" action=\"https://mattarahkka.happybooking.io/\">";
     $content .= "<table class=\"sideTable\"><tbody><tr>";
     $content .= "<span class=\"date-title\" style=\"padding: 0px\">Check-in</span>";
     $content .= "<input id=\"from\" name=\"from\" class=\"checkInsDate\" type=\"text\">";
     $content .= "</tr><tr>";
     $content .= "<span class=\"date-title\" style=\"padding: 0px\">Check-out</span>";
     $content .= "<input id=\"to\" name=\"to\" class=\"checkInsDate\" type=\"text\">";
     $content .= "</tr></tbody></table>";
     $content .= "<div class=\"buttonHolder\">";
     $content .= "<input class=\"btn\" value=\"Search available lodgings\" type=\"submit\">";
     $content .= "</div>";
     $content .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"lang\" value=\"English\"/>";
     $content .= "</form></div>";

     return $content;
    }
add_shortcode('happy-booking-widget','insert_booking_widget');

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'csf_booking_widget_custom_jquery');
```

The Js file (datepicker_2):

```
jQuery(function(){ 
    var dates = jQuery("#from, #to").datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    dayNamesMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
    weekHeader: "W.",
    monthNames: ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
        instance = jQuery(this).data("datepicker"),
        date = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(
            instance.settings.dateFormat ||
            jQuery.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
            selectedDate, instance.settings );
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
        autoclose: true;
    }

    });
});
```

Comment: Try adding the following to your onSelect function" `$('#ui-datepicker-div table td a').attr('href', 'javascript:;');`

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working as intended